# Need some book recommendations for my set theory hobbies

Tags: elementary-set-theory, book-recommendation

I'm in high school and I'm quite new to set theory. Off and on I've been surfing Wikipedia and other wikis to learn more about set theory, and right now I am working through a book called "A Book on Set Theory" by Charles C. Pinter, republished by Dover publications.

Basically, what I need is a thick book to go to next to study deeper into set theory. To add, I'm not at all afraid about writing page-long proofs as answers to exercise questions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*

Comment: pinter is very lucid and the introduction on axiomatization must be useful. But I think he works with " urelements" ( objects that are not sets themselves) and that this approach is not much standard. Why not start with Lipschutz, and then try Enderton?

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/basic-set-theory.html ( see the reading section)

Comment: more advanced : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/basic-set-theory.html

Comment: https://www.logicmatters.net/2012/10/09/teach-yourself-logic-4-beginning-set-theory/

Comment: See https://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf